# How do you change the iframe address used by Meteor Velocity

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity, codio

I am using [Codio](http://codio.com) for my Meteor development, so my app is not hosted at `localhost:3000` when I'm previewing it, it's actually at `random-name.codio.io:3000`, which I have to get to by visiting `random-name-3000.codio.io`, so when Velocity fires up its iframe to run client-side tests on it has the wrong address, like so: `<iframe src="http://localhost:5000/?mocha=true&amp;lastModified=1427105608181">`.

How do I convince Velocity to use `random-name-5000.codio.io` as its `src` instead of `localhost:5000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this when running the app, i think it's not correctly setting the app url root:

```
ROOT_URL=http://random-name.codio.io:3000 meteor --port=3000
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Cloud9. Any tips there? I've tried setting the ROOT_URL to the same sort of thing. Cloud 9 requires running the meteor app in the form:
meteor --port $IP:$PORT
The environment is:
IP = 0.0.0.0
PORT:8080

But when I go to the app the url is like:
https://appname-username.c9.io

and no ports are specified.