# What configuration of Cloud9 works with running Meteor, Velocity, and Mocha?

Tags: meteor, mocha.js, velocity, cloud9-ide

I've been trying to run through the example given here on Cloud9:
http://www.meteortesting.com/chapter/velocity

So when I get to the part about changing a working test to a broken test in sampleClientTest.js I run into a problem where Velocity does not run the client side tests.

I can add server side tests all day and that works fine (unless I specify ROOT_URL recommended by [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208003/how-do-you-change-the-iframe-address-used-by-meteor-velocity) which breaks the server side and the client side). I've also verified that it's not an issue with browser policy as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866008/mocha-web-client-side-tests-not-running-with-velocity-for-meteor-application).

I get the following error in the browser console:

> Blocked loading mixed active content
>   "http://0.0.0.0:5000/?mocha=true&lastModified=1428993591620"[Learn
>   More] blaze.js:383:0

What I'm not clear about is what settings I need to use to get Cloud9 and Mocha to play nice together so that the IP mocha uses is the right one (or at least the correct Cloud9 url which is in the form:

```
https://<appname>-<username>.c9.io
```

Any tips? Am I just not playing with the correct parameters of meteor/velocity to get it running?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I'm running into the same issues.

Comment: I did not, you may want to try the answer below. I will try the suggested solution tonight if possible and mark it accepted if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue this week, but figured it out. You can change where your app exports to(where it runs). This way, when you connect(oauth etc) with other applications(fb, google, twitter), they can all have the right url. In your command line, just type this $ export ROOT_URL='{your workspace url}' Enter your workspace name.

Check this question for reference: [Meteor accounts-twitter unable to get working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503844/meteor-accounts-twitter-unable-to-get-working)